# (LoadError) No such file or directory - wpscan

Tags: software-installation, system

Trying to install wpscan on my system. I have installed these following packages `libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev ruby-dev build-essential libgmp-dev zlib1g-dev`. I have downloaded wpscan from official github repository using git. Installed wpscan using bundler. Everything seems okay but when I try to run wpscan I get,

```
trevor@elementary:~/wpscan$ ruby wpscan.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby: No such file or directory -- wpscan.rb (LoadError)
```

Gems that were in the test group were ignored during installation, can this be the reason?

Comment: The error describes pretty much everything. Perform a `ls` to check wpscan.rb is there or not. I believe its not.

Comment: I saw this tutorial on hackertarget which instructed to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the things is nothing wrong here you can just run wpscan with `wpscan`. And don't forget to run **inside the wpscan folder**, unless you may get some other errors.
Go ahead and try `wpscan --url <yourdomain.tld>`, I believe it will work.

For further query related to wpscan (i.e. how to hack a site) you can get help from [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/) as it is kind of off-topic for this site.